# No-name Android app that can't be uninstalled

Tags: malware, android, mobile, spyware

Yesterday, I downloaded an apk outside the playstore and like a newbie (shame on me), I didn't check if it was secure or not. It was't working anyway, so I just removed the app. 
But now, I have this weird no-name application on my phone, and I can't delete it. And it opens everytime I check my messages or emails. It has a full network acces and a view on network connections. I think it's a spy...?

I don't know what to do and how remove it. And the thing I don't get is: how can you code an app which can't be deleted?
Do you have any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of "App info".]

Comment: When in doubt, treat as comprised until proven different. Steps you should take **right now** are: 1. Disable the apps permissions under Settings -> App-Permissions (or similar) 2. Change all passwords, treat each account as compromised. (Especially email) 3. Back up as much of your personal data as possible, possibly prepare for a reflash. 4. Disable all network connections on your phone, maybe even shut it down. I'm very sorry to be devils advocate, but this is best practice in security. Sadly, your phone is the center of your digital identity.

Comment: What was the name of that app?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm gonna try that right now. Well, that's the problem: it has no name: " "

Comment: Okay, so I succeed in removing the app, thank you for your advices. I disabled the application as a "Device Administration Application" and I removed it. I'm gonna change my password like you said, but do you think I should erase all my data from my phone? Even if the app was removed?

Comment: It depends on how careful you want to be. If I was you, I probably would **not** wipe it. Be warned though. If I solved your problem though, do you mind me posting it as an answer and you accepting it? It helps anyone experiencing similar problems. (BTW I meant the name of the app you downloaded :D)

Comment: Yeah, go ahead :) My phone is safe, thanks to you!

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site.

Answer (score 1):

**When in doubt, treat as compromised until proven different.**

---

Steps you should take right now are:

1. Disable all permissions of that App under Settings -> App-Permissions (or similar)
2. Remove the App from the list of *Device Administration Applications*.
3. Change all passwords, treat each account as compromised. (Especially email)
4. Back up as much of your personal data as possible, possibly prepare for a reflash.
5. Disable all network connections on your phone, maybe even shut it down. I'm very sorry to be devils advocate, but this is best practice in security. Sadly, your phone is the center of your digital identity.