# Suspicious Android app - install on its own - no uninstall option - name in Japanese

Tags: malware, android, account-security

I recently saw the app below in my phone. Have disabled it immediately when I saw it. Have no idea:

- what it is
- why it's in my phone
- how long it's been there
- and how to uninstall it (there's no uninstall option as you see in the screenshot)

[image]

Just wonder if anyone has experienced this issue (probably with another app, but pretty much same situation), and whether it's a security issue?

A few days ago, I installed a camera monitoring app called Xmeye (landlord installed the security camera, and told me that I can use this app to connect to it). Immediately uninstall the app after the first run as:

- it's from China
- it asks for access to phone call, contact, location (I did not grant it the access, so it did not even start. Though I did give it storage access)

Not sure if there's any link between this Xmeye app and the above app.

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152303/android-no-name-app-without-the-ability-to-remove-it) question is somehow similar, and the only answer suggests to disable all permissions for the suspicious app, but I found no permission for that one.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site. We cannot possibly know if the other app could be involved without inspecting your phone.

Comment: The name suggests it's a comic app (Manga) though that probably doesn't mean anything useful unless it jogs your memory of when it might have been installed.

Comment: The app's name is まんがお得 (*Manga O-toku*, Good-value Manga). Judging from the icon, it is by [ebookjapan](https://ebookjapan.yahoo.co.jp/), a legal online manga service in Japan (with Yahoo! Japan). However, to make things clear, we need [the app's package name](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name) first.